# Best way to Add/Remove records from large set of data on scroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance

I'm refactoring a ReactJS application at work that presents users with a large amount of content (1k+ records) and also allows them to apply complex filters to said content (ranges, toggles, exclusions, etc...)

Since, rendering a large amount of data like that is *very* taxing on the user's computer (particularly in IE11 or edge), I made the decision to only ever render a 100 part chunk, which substantially improved the performance (To paint a picture, response time reduced from seconds to miliseconds)

However, doing so introduced a new problem, because there is a requirement that the content *cannot* be paginated, the only available method to add/remove content records is when the user scrolls either up or down.

Unfortunately, the rendered chunk only allow the user to scroll so far before they hit the bottom of the page, which results in the user not being able to access all of the content.

**Question**
What's the best way to allow the user to scroll up/down so they can see *all* of the available content?

Here is what I have so far, which loads the content fine, but doesn't allow the user to see the entire dataset

**Component**

```js
class Layout extends React.PureComponent { 

    constructor( props ){
        super( props );
        this.state = {
            scroll: 0
        };
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        document.addEventListener( 'scroll', this.handleScroll )
    }

    componentDidUpdate( prevProps, prevState ){
        if( prevState.scroll !== this.state.scroll ){
            this.props.setChunk( ( prevState.scroll < this.state.scroll ) ? DIRECTION_DOWN : DIRECTION_UP );
        }
    }

    // this updates the state on scroll provided the scroll surpases a threshold so we aren't constantly hitting the reducer
    handleScroll = () => {
        let scroll = window.scrollY;
        if( scroll < ( this.state.scroll + SCROLL_THRESHOLD ) && scroll > ( this.state.scroll - SCROLL_THRESHOLD ) ) return;
        this.setState({ scroll });
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <Title />
                <Tools />
                <Table />
            </React.Fragment> 
        );
    }
}
```

**Reducer**

```
case CONSTANTS.SET_CHUNK:

    // determines which direction the records should be added/removed from
    let startIndex = ( action.payload.direction === CONFIG.DIRECTION_UP ) ? ( state.startIndex - 1 ) : ( state.startIndex + 1 ),

    // the chunk of data to be displayed
    chunk = state.data.slice( startIndex, CONFIG.CHUNK_SIZE );

    // prevents the user from scrolling to a non-existant index
    if( startIndex < 0 || startIndex > ( state.data.length - 1 ) ) return { ...state };

    return { ...state, startIndex, chunk };
```

Comment: have you checked out https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized? could use a library to handle the long list rendering

Comment: I haven't, but i'm definitely going to look into that immediately

Answer (score 0):

I would think 'infinite scroll' would be a good solution here. As such, you would only load the next lot of data when your user hits the bottom of the current list.

Comment: infinite scroll would work, but if the user scrolls all the way to the bottom you will still have the entire list which will be very heavy and slow to update

Comment: ah perhaps you can lop off some from the top when the new data loads in or something?